Inconsistent behaviour of procedure in Maple
I don't understand the behaviour of the following code:
a := proc($n, k$)
if $n = 0$ then return $100$;
else return $k(k - 1)^{n - 1}$;
end if;
end proc;
sum(a$(n, 2)x^n, n = 0 .. 1$);
$$2 + 2 x$$
a$(0, 2)$ + a$(1, 2)x$; $$100 + 2x$$

Does the error persist if you change the index you're summing over from $n$ to something else?

The sum tries to do its best to first simplify the summand—with a generic index ($n$)—then it tries to find the sum. However, your $a(n,k)$ is just a generic procedure; it's a code it executes. When it does so with an unassigned variable $n$, the condition $n=0$ is not satisfied, so it goes to the else branch and returns $k(k - 1)^{n - 1}$; in this case, for $k=2$, it's just $2$. So in the end it wants to evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{1}2x^n=2+2x$.
What you can do instead is use add instead of sum, then each term is actually evaluated with a specific value of $n$, with no optimization performed.
Alternatively, you can define $a(n,k)$ as a piecewise function, then the sum will be able to optimize it better. For example:
a:=(n,k)->piecewise(n=0,100,k*(k-1)^(n-1));
sum(a(n,2)*x^n,n=0..1);

In your case, you have a small sum and there is not much to optimize, so it does not really matter which approach you use; both give the correct result. In general, if you don't expect any optimization or if you use procedures, add is a better choice. For larger sums, and if there is a "hope" for a simplification, the benefit of sum shows. A classic example is a sum of an arithmetic progression: sum will use the well-known formula, whereas add will actually add all the terms.
